# Get Namespace, classname from a dll in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, reflection, namespaces, classname

I will get dll's dynamically. I need to load the dll and get the namespace, classname to invoke a method (the method name is static it will be always "OnStart()").
Basically I need to run a method by loading the dll. Can somebody help!!!.

Answer (score 14):

To load the assembly, you would do this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"test.dll");
```

This assumes you have the assemblies on disk as files. If you don't, like if you get them from a database as a byte array, there are other methods on the [Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx) that will help you give you an Assembly object after loading it.

To iterate through all the classes in the assembly, you would do this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"test.dll");
foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (type.IsClass)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

To find the OnStart static method, you would do this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"test.dll");
foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (type.IsClass)
    {
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("OnStart",
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (method != null)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

To call the method, you would do this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"test.dll");
foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (type.IsClass)
    {
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("OnStart",
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (method != null)
        {
            method.Invoke(null, new Object[0]); // assumes no parameters
            break; // no need to look for more methods, unless you got multiple?
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to pass arguments to the method, you would put them in an object array:

```
Object[] arguments = new Object[] { arg1, arg2, arg3 ... };
method.Invoke(null, arguments);
```

The above code can be collapsed to the following by using Linq to find the method for us:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"test.dll");
var method = (from type in assembly.GetTypes()
              where type.IsClass
              let onStartMethod = type.GetMethod("OnStart",
                  BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
              where onStartMethod != null
              select onStartMethod).FirstOrDefault();
if (method != null)
{
    method.Invoke(null, new Object[0]); // assumes no parameters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       object result = null;

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ASSEMBLYPATH, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), false))
        {
            byte[] b = new byte[reader.BaseStream.Length];
            reader.BaseStream.Read(b, 0, Convert.ToInt32(reader.BaseStream.Length));
            reader.Close();

            Assembly asm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(b);
            Type typeClass = asm.GetType(CLASSFULLNAME); // including namespace
            MethodInfo mi = typeClass.GetMethod("OnStart");
            ConstructorInfo ci = typeClass.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
            object responder = ci.Invoke(null);

            // set parameters
            object[] parameters = new object[1];
            parameters[0] = null;  // no params


            result = mi.Invoke(responder, parameters);
        }
```

The advantage using this code is that the assembly is unloaded after use, so you can safely delete the dll after invoking the method.

Answer (score 0):

Check here: http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2008/12/reflection-in-c-list-of-class-name.html

And here for invoking a method: http://www.csharphelp.com/archives/archive200.html

If you search some more the terms in those links you'll find much more info.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime namespaces just become part of the type name.

So you need to:

1. Load the assembly
2. Get the Type instance for the type you want.
3. Get the `MethodInfo` for the method you want to call.
4. Call the method.

Of these 2–4 are easy. 1 *might* be easy or might not, depending where the assembly is. Assuming the assembly can be found via the normal assembly load ("probing"). This will call a public static method of a type that takes no arguments but does have a return value.

```
var asm = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
var t = asm.GetType(typeName);
// Pass array of parameter types to resolve between overloads (here no arguments).
var m = t.GetMathod(methodName, BindingFlags.Static, null, new Type[] {}, null);
// Pass no "this" or arguments.
var res = (resultType) m.Invoke(null, null);
```

A number of the details here will depend on the details of the assembly, type and method you want to call.