# Get reference dll name used for our project with class name

Tags: c#, .net, dll, namespaces, .net-assembly

How do you get all the reference dll name and their represent class name with namespace used in particular dll  reflection in C#?

let us consider sample.dll in which reference1.dll and reference2.dll is used as reference to the sample dll through method reference1.method1 and reference2.method2

i need to list out

```
1)reference dll names ie.reference1.dll,reference2.dll
2)methods used in that dll names ie.reference1.method1,reference2.method2
3) Namespace used for referring that reference dll
```

i have tried with `myassembly.GetTypes()` it does no help me out

waiting for your responses

Comment: This might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593500/get-namespace-classname-from-a-dll-in-c-sharp-2-0

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'm not sure why you think `Assembly.GetTypes()` doesn't help...

Note that not all dll's are on disk, so if you `Assembly.Location` instead of name then you may encounter an error.

Namespaces don't refer to a specific Assembly, an Assembly can contain many namespaces.

The method below will include a fair chunk of the .Net framework, so you may want to filter the list down a little bit.

Does this help?

```
        List<String> Dlls = new List<string>();
        List<String> Namespaces = new List<string>();
        List<String> Methods = new List<string>();
        foreach (var Assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            if (!Dlls.Contains(Assembly.GetName().Name))
                Dlls.Add(Assembly.GetName().Name);

            foreach (var Type in Assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                if (!Namespaces.Contains(Type.Namespace))
                    Namespaces.Add(Type.Namespace);
                foreach(var Method in Type.GetMethods())
                {
                    Methods.Add(String.Format("{0}.{1}", Type.Name, Method.Name));
                }
            }

        }
```